# On rewrite $_GET is lost

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Doing a rewrite in my htaccess file I loose the ID in the $_GET request.

My Rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ post.php?id=$1&name=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]
```

MY url is: example.com/post.php?id=7&name=Post-6

With my rewrite this version works: example.com/7

But not example.com/post/Post-6

How can I make the $_GET ID get passed when I want the url to look only like this:

example.com/post/Post-6

The full htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^product/(.*).html$ products.php?q=$1&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [B,L]

RewriteRule ^merchant/$ merchants.php
RewriteRule ^merchant/(.*)/$ search.php?q=merchant:$1:&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [B,L]
RewriteRule ^merchant/(.*)/(.*).html$ search.php?q=merchant:$1:&page=$2&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [B,L]

RewriteRule ^category/$ categories.php [L]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/$ categories.php?path=$1  [L,B]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*).html$ search.php?q=category:$1:&page=$2&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,B]

RewriteRule ^brand/$ brands.php
RewriteRule ^brand/(.*)/$ search.php?q=brand:$1:&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [B,L]
RewriteRule ^brand/(.*)/(.*).html$ search.php?q=brand:$1:&page=$2&rewrite=1&%{QUERY_STRING} [B,L]

RewriteRule ^blog\/ blog.php
RewriteRule ^blog\/?p=1 blog\/ [L]
RewriteRule ^post/(.*)$ post.php?id=$1&name=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# special MIME type for icons - see http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/vnd.microsoft.icon
AddType image/vnd.microsoft.icon .ico
# now we have icon MIME type, we can use it
# my favicon doesn't change much
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 3 months"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch ".(js|xml|css|gz|html)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule on top of your .htaccess to turn off `MultiViews`:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

It is due to the fact you have this rule where `post` is same word in source and target URIs:

```
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: What should be `name` and `id` values in your URL: `example.com/post/Post-6`

Comment: So `example.com/post/Post-6` should give you `id=6` and `name=Post-6` ?

Answer (score 0):

May be

> RewriteRule ^post/(.*)/(.*)$ post.php?id=$1&name=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA,L]

Comment: Sorry i understand wrongly. What you want give and get?

Comment: Giving "example.com/post/Post-6", and getting "example.com/post.php?id=6&name=Post" ??